# MPAndroid Chart same chart width

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]

I try to figure out, how to set the same width for both of these charts.
The yAxis labels may change, so all I need is to set the effective chart width of the second chart to the width of the first one.
Anyone tips on how to implement this?
Also I try to drag and scale them together. I can't find anything about this and there is no (?) example on how to make this happen.
I started with a listener for the gestures...

Comment: have you tried to adjust the space between individual bars and dataSets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add below line in your code.

```
mChart.setViewPortOffsets(50f, 0f, 50f, 0f);
```

in this, `mChart` is object of `LineChart`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the function I can work with. I only have to check the width of my yAxis, because this can be 1..5 digits wide, so I have to dynamically change this.
Problem 1/3 solved! THANK YOU!